# What is the most "efficient" closed-form expression for approximating a transcendental number?

Tags: number-theory, analysis, transcendental-numbers

$\frac{9}{5}+\sqrt{\frac{9}{5}}=3.1416...$ is a closed-form approximation of $\pi$ with a precision of 3 digits. After reading the wiki page on [approximations of pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80), I read about many clever methods for finding closed-form approximations of $\pi$. I was curious how much "information" you can pack in a closed-form expression to approximate some transcendental number. I wouldn't know how to measure the "efficiency" of a closed-form expression. For instance, the number of integers in the expression divided by the the number of digits of precision. That way, you get information divided by precision. Is there a limit to how much you can pack in an expression?

Comment: Quite a bit is known about the "most efficient" approximation of a transcendental number by *rational* numbers with a cost measured by combined digits of the numerator and denominator.  Less is known about algebraic approximations, though for quadratic numbers there are some results.  Of course any measure of the size of an expression will produce a finite number of possibilities of any particular kind, and thus limit the precision of such expressions.

Comment: @hardmath Interesting. Do you know any resources that go into algebraic approximations?

Comment: If you can use arctangent, $4\arctan(1)$ is probably the most "efficient." Infinite precision!

Comment: Convergents (truncated values) and semi-convergents of the continued fraction of $x$ are its best rational approximations in the sense that they are closer than any other fraction with the same or smaller denominator, see [Best rational approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations).

Comment: @SpencerKraisler I'm not using pi per se, and even if using arctangent is considered using pi, the approximation you give, $20\arctan(1/7)+\cdots$ also uses pi, so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments here, the expression:

$$ \pi = 20 \arctan \frac{1}{7} + 8 \arctan \frac{3}{79} $$

has a "precision of over $12$ digits" only in the sense that it is an exact equation. The transcendental number $\pi$ is expressed as a sum of two more transcendental numbers.

That is an expression due to Euler among a class of exact representations commonly called [Machin-like formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula) after John Machin, who gave (1706):

$$ \pi = 16 \arctan \frac{1}{5} - 4 \arctan \frac{1}{239}  $$

and used it to compute $\pi$ to a thousand decimal places.  The "simplest" of these exact expressions was also found by Euler:

$$ \pi = 4 \arctan \frac{1}{2} + 4 \arctan \frac{1}{3} $$

but it is less practical for computation because of the relatively slow convergence at these arguments of the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions) of $\arctan x$.

But since these are not "approximations" of a transcendental number by algebraic numbers, the remainder of this post will point out references pertinent to that general subject (and not solely to approximating $\pi$).

---

Most authors begin their treatment of this subject by revisiting the approximation of real numbers by rational numbers, This classic "Diophantine" topic is fully developed by Knuth in [AOCP Vol. II, Semi-numerical Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming#Volume_2_%E2%80%93_Seminumerical_Algorithms), and has been previously been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139381/good-and-best-rational-approximations) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516416/about-continued-fractions-as-best-rational-approximations) at Math.SE in terms of continued fraction convergents and [semi-convergents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856861/semi-convergent-of-continued-fractions).

The basic result, going back to [Dirichlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem), is that for any *irrational* real number $r$, there exist an infinite number of *rational approximations* $p/q$ such that:

$$ \left| r - \frac{p}{q} \right| \lt \frac{1}{q^2} $$

where $p,q$ are coprime and $q\gt 0$, and one way to obtain such approximations is from the [convergents of the simple continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of $r$.  By allowing the denominator $q$ to grow large, we obtain rational approximations as close to $r$ as we wish.  But if $q$ is bounded, then there are only finitely many such approximations, and the best precision is therefore limited.

To generalize this to approximation of transcendental real numbers by *algebraic numbers*, it was conjectured by Eduard Wirsing (1960) that for any real $\xi$ not algebraic of degree $d$ or less over the integers, there are an infinite number of algebraic numbers $\alpha$ of degree $d$ or less over the integers such that:

$$ \left| \xi - \alpha \right| < c H(\alpha)^{-(d+1)} $$

where $c$ is a positive constant (depending on $\xi$) and "height" $H(\alpha)$ is the maximum absolute value of coefficients in the minimal integer polynomial of $\alpha$.

This conjecture remains an open problem, but was proven for *almost all* real numbers by V. Sprindžuk (1965). For $d=2$ it was proven without exceptions by [Harold Davenport and Wolfgang M. Schmidt (1967)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davenport%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem).

There is a book-length treatment by Yann Bugeaud (Cambridge Univ. Press, 2004) titled *Approximation by Algebraic Numbers*.  See also the [survey by Vladislav Frank (2007)](http://algant.eu/documents/theses/frank.pdf), "Approximation to real numbers by algebraic numbers of bounded degree" at the level of a Master's Thesis.

Comment: $\pi=4\arctan 1$ is probably simpler.

Comment: @KentaS: No reasonable person would deny it is simpler, but it does not fall into the class of Machin-like formulas!  This [text file](http://www.super-computing.org/pi_current.html) gives an account of record setting digits of $\pi$ computations, and sketches the attractions of more complicated formulas (both for rapidity of convergence and for self-checking the accuracy).